# gmock with base class constructor

Tags: c++, googlemock

I'm getting a compiler error, which I don't understand why. Or rather, I believe I'm doing what it telling me to. (Or not doing what I shouldn't do)

```
// InterfaceClass.h
class InterfaceClass {
 public:
    explicit InterfaceClass(DependencyClass * const p_dc);
};

// MockClass.h
class MockClass : public InterfaceClass {
 public:
    explicit MockClass(DependencyClass * const p_dc) : InterfaceClass(p_dc) {}
};

// test_MyTest.cpp
class MyTestFixture : public testing::Test {
 protected:
    MockDependencyClass mock_dependency;
    NiceMock<mocks::MockClass> mock;
 public:
    MyTestFixture() : mock(&mock_depedency) {}
};
```

The error I'm getting when compiling my test is this:

```
In file included from test/test_MyTest.cpp:2:
In file included from vendor/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:62:
vendor/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-generated-nice-strict.h:92:12: error: constructor for 'testing::NiceMock<MockClass>' must explicitly initialize the base class 'InterfaceClass' which does not have a default constructor
  explicit NiceMock(const A1& a1) : MockClass(a1) {
           ^
test/test_MyTest.cpp:43:30: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'testing::NiceMock<MockClass>::NiceMock<DependencyClass *>' requested here
    MyTestFixture(void) : mock(&mock_dependency) {
                          ^
src/InterfaceClass:21:7: note: 'InterfaceClass' declared here
class InterfaceClass {
      ^
```

So, if I'm understanding this correctly, its telling me that my mock cannot initialise the interface class, because there is no default constructor and I haven't specified a non-default constructor to use. But I have? And if I understand gmock's source correctly, it supports constructors with up to 10 parameters.

And in my test fixture; if I make the mock a regular mock (i.e. not a NiceMock), it compiles.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what happens when you delete explicit from constructor definition?